# How to fix the bar chart negative value go through downwards from 0 to -ve value?

Tags: jquery, graph, charts

I have use jQuery plugin for graph utility. This plot the negative value starts from negative.

Below i include the image

[image: Bar chart representation with negative value]

How to fix this.

Comment: is the graphic library capable of drawing negative value charts?

Comment: There is a negative sign on y axis. may be it has negative value charts. Now i choose this one to work with the sample code to work on it. And i study the plugin first and start work on it. Do u have any plugin for negative value capable chart utility?

Comment: here is a nice one :http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. This is a good. but i try to jqplot. I read the documentation. No detailed about negative value support in this plugin. kindly tell about jqplot is support or not negative values chart.

Comment: see last exemple from http://www.jqplot.com/examples/barTest.php

Comment: This example is very clear to explain the negative value support. thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

I miss the code part the 'seriesDefaults:'

```
rendererOptions:{
                fillToZero: true
            }
```

Now I include this one. To display the negative values correctly.